# How to test Dungenos Sample BillingApp using Device?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I just downlaod this app now What I have to do for test this sample app on device.
Without Upload any application on android market can I tested this sample billing app.??
It is necessary to signed with my publisher account to test this sample billing app??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using one of the four test flags, like android.test.purchased. You do not have to signed your app to test. Just install the app, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply    But using this test flags..I am unable to purchase anything..I want to see the demostration of purchase any item how i achieve this

Comment: 1. you have to create an item in your market account.
2. you have to sign your app with your key.
3. upload the app to the market.
these are the minimal steps, come back if you get stuck.